# How to get browser serial id which never change for particular system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

I want to store the unique id of browser which never change for that system. 
I want to check that whenever my site runs in the any browser i want to store that browser data like **[browser name, version, platform,and one unique id/serial id]**.
Is there any way that i can get the unique id for each browser for one system?
i checked some node package managers, but not satisfied.

Comment: There is no such thing as an invariant unique id for a browser.  You can create a unique id and put it in a cookie for that browser and most of the time you will get that cookie back with the unique id in it, but sometimes users clear their cookies or run tools that block cookies or run in modes that don't save cookies.  And, please note the cookie will identify the browser, not the user.  It could be a different user on the same browser.  You will have to require a login in order to identify a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in node.js you can get that information from `req.headers['user-agent']`

for more information about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent